# Preamble parametrization - passing parameters to `\usepackage`

Tags: preamble, package-options

I have CV in two languages, which share most of the preamble but `\usepackage[<language>]{babel}`.

I want to parametrize the preamble similarly to:

```
\usepackage[\cvLanguage]{babel}
\usepackage{doi}
```

and use it in the main `\LaTeX` file like:

```
\newcommand{\cvLanguage}{english}
\input{preamble.tex}
```

That mysteriously failed:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ...onefilewithoptions #1[{\cvLanguage 
                                                  }][{}]\noexpand \@pkgexten...
l.36 \usepackage
                {doi}
```

thus I asked the question.  The failure cannot be replicated, that is my approach works, but the question has received two good answers already thus I leave it for future generations.

Comment: Your error shows that you didn't define `\cvLanguage`, so you didn't use the code fragment you show in your question. Can you please provide a complete minimal example of the code you're actually using that produces your error?

Comment: There is no minimal failing example - I am unable to reproduce.  I think the problem might be with may build.  Probably I failed to save the file when I edited it to define the `\cvLanguage`...  Should I delete the question?

Comment: Not now, that it has several answers showing working approaches. This way it can serve as examples for future visitors.

Comment: @Skillmon That is what I thought.  See my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of putting your preamble in a `.tex` file create your own package and use LaTeX's option-mechanism to forward your language to `babel`. The following adds key=value options using the LaTeX-kernel's build in mechanism for this.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mypreamble.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypreamble}
\DeclareKeys{language .store = \cvLanguage, language .usage = load}
\SetKeys{language=english}% initial value
\ProcessKeyOptions
\RequirePackage[\cvLanguage]{babel}
\RequirePackage{doi}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[language=english]{mypreamble}

\begin{document}
Some document using \cvLanguage.
\end{document}
```

---

*Shameless advertising:*

Alternative implementation using `expkv-opt` and `expkv-def` instead of the LaTeX kernel's key=value implementation (I'm `expkv`'s author):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mypreamble.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypreamble}
\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{mypreamble}
  { store language = \cvLanguage, initial language = english }
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{mypreamble} % ignore options handed to \documentclass
\RequirePackage[\cvLanguage]{babel}
\RequirePackage{doi}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[language=english]{mypreamble}

\begin{document}
Some document using \cvLanguage.
\end{document}
```

---

Both code blocks produce:

[image]

Comment: I am not advanced in `\LaTeX`, is replacement of `\usepackage` with `\RequirePackage` the only change required in the code of preamble?  I use another `\input`, `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, `\renewcommand*`, `\RenewDocumentCommand`, `\newlength`, `\setlength`, `\settowidth`, `\addtolength`, `\pagestyle`, `\bibliographystyle`, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` there.

Comment: @abukaj If you're using a package you don't need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (LaTeX does a `\makeatletter` at the start of the package for you, and a `\makeatother` at the end -- without breaking nested packages). Everything else should be fine. The `\usepackage` to `\RequirePackage` is only necessary to allow the package to be loaded before `\documentclass` via `\RequirePackage` itself, but it is good practice to use that inside of packages.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\def` instead of `\newcommand`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{preamble.tex}
    \usepackage[\cvLanguage]{babel}
    \usepackage[\ForVisualEffect]{geometry} % not needed, just for demo reasons
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\def\cvLanguage{english}
\def\ForVisualEffect{showframe} % not needed, just for demo reasons
\input{preamble.tex}

\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

Here I also added a similar example where the `geometry` package gets the `showframe` option to have a visual proof that it works.

[image: Result]

Comment: Why should `\def` be better in this case than `\newcommand`? The error OP shows is that `\cvLanguage` is still undefined.

Comment: @Skillmon To be honest, I did not check whether it works with `\newcommand` (and it does indeed). I just built something which does, what OP wants: write the language to `\cvLanguage` and use it in the preamble.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: Unless you know what you're doing, use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`. For this application, `\newcommand` should be preferred, imho.